# Can I use EE fieldnames in Freeform form tag?

Tags: solspace-freeform

This isn’t a code question - yet - but here’s a quick overview of my setup so that you have some context:

- EE 2.5.3
- Freeform 4.0.08

I have a template that includes a form. The template displays an individual person’s information, which is held in an EE channel entry (one entry per person). There are upwards of 20 people whose information is displayed via this particular template.

I would like the person whose information is currently displayed, to receive any notifications that a user may send in using the form on the page. I have an EE channel field, {lo_email}. As long as the Freeform tag is contained within the exp:channel:entries tag, can I use that fieldname in the Freeform tag, to target the person receiving notifications from the form? Example:

```
{exp:freeform:form admin_notify="{lo_email}"}
```

(I haven’t tried this yet - but this needs to get done quickly, so I thought I’d ask if this is possible before doing some template restructuring on this site that I’ve inherited.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, this should work. I've done this frequently on a more complex scale, using channel entries to offer customizable Freeform forms for clients.

Comment: Most excellent. I'm making an event RSVP form, and containing the freeform form means I can pass all kinds of info about the event in hidden fields that I then call on in the notification emails.